# Why is this SQL query coming up with "Could not find installable ISAM"?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oledbconnection

This C# code is supposed to execute a query to a SQL database, but it doesn't work correctly, and comes up with the error shown below. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to resolve this?

Here is the SQL connection string:

```
"Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=" + dbServer + ";uid=" + dbUser + ";pwd=" + dbPwd + ";database='" + dbName + "';"

Example: "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=10.0.1.233;uid=username;pwd=password1;database=databasename;"
```

Error below:

```
7:17:03 PM, Sunday, August 09, 2015, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Could not find installable ISAM.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at NSClient.NSClient.CheckIDUpdate()
   at NSClient.NSClient.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Does your username or password have any odd characters in it, like `;` for example?

Comment: Post the query. Is it referring to a linked server? i.e. `SELECT * FROM Server.database.schema.Table`. Have you tried running the exact query directly in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/connect-via-an-ip-address/), you need to specify the protocol when using an IP.

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

> DBMSSOCN=TCP/IP. This is how to use TCP/IP instead of Named Pipes. At
>   the end of the Data Source is the port to use. 1433 is the default
>   port for SQL Server. Read more in the article [How to define which
>   network protocol to use](http://www.connectionstrings.com/define-sql-server-network-protocol/).

Comment: @JordanJohnson. Did this really fix your problem? Because the error has nothing to so with network libraries and the Network Library is not required in the connection string. Have you ever searched for a solution on the internet, found an answer and discovered it didn't help?